# How to pass the rest of the props to an HTML element using svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I stuck a bit with a problem:

I have a svelte component, which works with a number of props:

```
<script>
    export let foo;
    export let bar;

</script>
```

But also, I'd like to pass some props to my HTML element directly.
So my solution is:

```
<script>
    export let foo;
    export let bar;

    const {
        foo,
        bar,
        ...other
    } = $$props;
</script>

<button {...other}>
    Some action
</button>
```

This one has a huge problem:
When I change some props like "class", the component wouldn't be updated.

```
<MyComponent {foo} {bar} class={condition ? 'one' : 'two'} />
```

What is a better way to solve this case? I mean, I have to support different props, not only "class" one.
How could I pass the rest of the props to an HTML-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... Passing class this way does work for me. See this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c69ec1b6e9154ede8826385127f1ee36?version=3).

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte'
    
    let checked
</script>

<label>
  <input type=checkbox bind:checked />
    Blue?
</label>

<MyComponent class={checked ? 'blue' : 'red'} />
```

`MyComponent.svelte`

```
<script>
  export let foo
  export let bar
</script>

<pre>foo={foo} bar={bar}</pre>

<button {...$$restProps}>
  Some button
</button>

<style>
    :global(.red) {
        color: red;
    }
    :global(.blue) {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

A couple notes...

Svelte has quite recently introduced `$$restProps` ([docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props) -- end of the section), which might be better suited that filtering props manually.

This block of code in your example is *not reactive*:

```js
    const {
        foo,
        bar,
        ...other
    } = $$props;
```

It is only executed once when the component is created. It is not updated when props change, which might explain why your subsequent change of props (`class={condition ? 'one' : 'two'}`) is not reflected.

If you need to do something like this (say because you need more control than what `$$restProps` offers out of the box), you need to put this in a reactive block (`$:`).

For example:

```
$: ({ foo, bar, ...other } = $$props)
```

The above JS syntax is equivalent to the following, more verbose, alternative:

```
let foo
let bar
$: {
  foo = $$props.foo
  bar = $$props.bar
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice! I didn't know $$restProps exists.